# Trying to change layer paint property but getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have a map with a layer image icon and I want to change the paint property when the layer is clicked on. Here is the code:

```
    function simpleChatSubmit() {
        map.current.loadImage(oneohsix, function (error, image) {
            if (error) throw error;
            map.current.addImage('popup', image, {
                pixelRatio: 2
            });

            console.log(geoData)

            map.current.addSource('points', {
                'type': 'geojson',
                'data': geoData
            });

            map.current.addLayer({
                'id': 'pointsLayer',
                'type': 'symbol',
                'source': 'points',
                'layout': {
                    // 'text-field': ['get', 'mag'],
                    'icon-text-fit': 'both',
                    'icon-image': ['get', 'image-name'],
                    'icon-allow-overlap': true,
                    'text-allow-overlap': true,
                    'icon-anchor': 'bottom-right'
                }
            });
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        map.current.on('click', 'pointsLayer', (e) => {
            map.current.setPaintProperty('pointsLayer', 'fill-color', '#faafee');
        });
    });
```

But when the layer is clicked on I am getting the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`. This happens on `setPaintProperty` not `.on('click`

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: [`fill-color`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-fill-fill-color) property only exists if the `type: fill` but you have `type: symbol`. I think you are looking for [`icon-color`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-symbol-icon-color). You should also figure out which line of code is erroring. What happens if you console log `map.current.getLayer('pointsLayer')`?

Comment: @Taku `console.log(map.current.getLayer('pointsLayer'))` returns this: `fh {id: "pointsLayer", type: "symbol", _featureFilter: {…}, metadata: undefined, minzoom: undefined, …}` so I think that's good. I changed  `fill-color` to `icon-color` and still no change

Comment: Do you want to create a [jsfiddle](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/simple-map/) to reproduce this?

Comment: @Taku I put my project here: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-sinoussi-zddwk?file=/src/App.js. Unfortunately the layers aren't loading. Do you know why this is?

Comment: You need to call the style related code after `map.current.on("load", () => {})`. Why don't you remove the code that is not relevant to the issue you see, so some layers can be removed? Also, there are several errors in the console which could be blocking this.

Comment: @Taku I figured out the `Error{}` is coming from `map.current.addSource("points", {})`. Any reason why this might be?

Comment: You can open up the console log and see what the error tells you. It's not parsing the GeoJSON string. You need to pass in `JSON.parse(geoData)`

Comment: Ok. It's working now. Does that help you?

Comment: I see your map located in Boston but your data is in Colorado; so your data is visible. You can also verify your geojson geomtry using [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/). I also don't see the error that you described in the original post. What can one do to reproduce that?

Comment: I'm trying to have the application change the color of the icon. I was reading the docs and it looked like setPaintProperty was the way to do that but it isn't working (I assume as intended)

Comment: Yes, you can use that method to set properties, but I didn't see that implementation in the sample. The property names depend on what the layer is, for example `type: symbol` or `type:fill`. You can [read the docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#symbol) about what you want to set for the layer type.

Comment: Ok. I added `map.current.setPaintProperty('pointsLayer', 'icon-color', '#faafee');` but as you can see it's not changing the color. Do you know why that is?